# Solve ODE of the form $X(t)+Y(t)X(t)'=G(t)$ for $X(t)$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I have this ode as the following,

$$\lambda(t)^\prime+p(t)\lambda(t)=G(t)$$

I need to solve for $\lambda(t)$. Any suggestion or hint is much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the standard [first-order linear differential equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_differential_equation#First-order_equation_with_variable_coefficients). The way I was taught to solve it was to introduce an integrating factor, $\mu (t)$ on both sides that would simplify the problem:
$$\mu(t)\lambda^\prime(t)+\mu(t)p(t)\lambda(t) = \mu(t)G(t)$$
Specifically, we want a $\mu (t)$ that satisfies $\mu^\prime(t) = p(t)\mu(t)$ so that we can apply the product rule for differentiation to the left side of the equation:
$$\mu(t)\lambda^\prime(t)+\mu(t)p(t)\lambda(t) = \mu(t)\lambda^\prime(t)+\mu^\prime(t)\lambda(t) = (\mu(t)\lambda(t))^\prime$$
It so happens that such a $\mu(t)$ is easy to find: what function's derivative looks like itself times a variable factor? The exponential function! If we let $\mu(t) = e^{\int{p(t)dt}}$, then it's not hard to see that, via the chain rule:
$$\mu^\prime(t) = \frac{d}{dt}(e^{\int{p(t)dt}}) = \frac{d}{dt}(\int{p(t)dt})e^{\int{p(t)dt}} = p(t)\mu(t)$$
as desired.

Armed with this, we can tackle the differential equation. Equate the right-hand sides of the first two equations, then integrate with respect to t and solve:
$$(\mu(t)\lambda(t))^\prime = \mu(t)G(t)$$
$$\mu(t)\lambda(t) = \int{\mu(t)G(t)dt}$$
$$\lambda(t) = \frac{1}{\mu(t)}\int{\mu(t)G(t)dt}$$
Substituting in our definition of $\mu(t)$, we get:
$$\lambda(t) = \frac{1}{e^{\int{p(t)dt}}}\int{G(t)e^{\int{p(t)dt}}dt}$$